# What does "Key to choose 5th level" in gnome-keyboard-properties do?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, xmodmap

There is an option to specify a key to be used to access 5th level on the keyboard in `gnome-keyboard-properties` ("Keyboard" under Hardware in System settings):

[image: Screenshot of said dialog]

But if I set the 5th level to <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the third level to <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> and if I set key 54 as follows:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 54 = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

I get following results from pressing different variations:

```
keycode 54 = 1
keycode 54 + right ctrl = 5
keycode 54 + right ctrl + shift = 6
keycode 54 + shift = 2
keycode 54 + AltGr = 1
keycode 54 + AltGr + shift = 2
```

1. So what does the 5th level modifier do?
2. How do I set it up so that I can get 5 or six different characters out of a single key (modified by <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> for example)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

“1. So what does the 5th level modifier do?”

It chooses the fifth level.  The 2nd level modifier (just regular shift)
chooses the second level, and the 3rd level chooses the third level.

The reason that the 5th level modifier chooses the fifth level instead
of the fourth level (right after the 3rd level modifier) is that these
three modifiers can be combined in different ways to choose eight
different level (this includes not using any of the modifiers, which is
just pressing a key without any such modifiers).  There are eight
combinations since 2↑3 = 8.  For the first two modifiers there are four
combinations:

- No modifiers (level 1)
- 2nd level modifier, a.k.a. shift (level 2)
- 3rd level modifier (level 3)
- 2nd + 3rd modifier (level 4)

Adding the third modifier (5th level) adds four more levels.

“2.  How do I set it up so that I can get 5 or six different characters
out of a single key (modified by Shift, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> and <kbd>Right
Ctrl</kbd> for example)?”

First of all you need a layout which uses five or more characters per
key.  You can choose an existing layout, but if you simply want to add
more levels to the layout you are currently using, that might not be
optimal.  For example, there is the [Neo](http://neo-layout.org/index_en.html) keyboard layout (†1), but that
is “optimized for the German Language” so not that great for most
English speakers.

Still, it might be instructive to have a look at what keys Neo has
chosen for the level 5 modifier.

[image: Neo layout]

Neo apparently calls the level 5 modifier for “Mod4”.  So as you can see
it uses the key to the right of the left shift key (`LSGT`) and the
right alt key/`AltGr` key.  This is on a European keyboard (105 keys)
which compared to the US keyboard (104 keys) has a narrow left shift and
tall and thin return key.  For a keyboard layout which is based on the
US keyboard one might have to—or prefer to—choose other keys.

## Choosing a level 5 modifier key

In sup’s answer he chooses to use Xmodmap.  Nowadays tools like
Setxkbmap is recommended over Xmodmap.  Xkb comes with many predefined
options for things like choosing the level 5 modifier.  If you consult
[man xkeyboard-config](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config#Options-Key_to_choose_5th_level) and search for `lv5` you’ll find these options:

```
┌──────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Option               │ Description                                       │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ lv5:lsgt_switch_lock │ <Less/Greater> chooses 5th level; acts as onetime │
│                      │ lock when pressed together with another 5th level │
│                      │ chooser                                           │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ lv5:ralt_switch_lock │ Right Alt chooses 5th level; acts as onetime lock │
│                      │ when pressed together with another 5th level      │
│                      │ chooser                                           │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ lv5:lwin_switch_lock │ Left Win chooses 5th level; acts as onetime lock  │
│                      │ when pressed together with another 5th level      │
│                      │ chooser                                           │
├──────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ lv5:rwin_switch_lock │ Right Win chooses 5th level; acts as onetime lock │
│                      │ when pressed together with another 5th level      │
│                      │ chooser                                           │
└──────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So the options that are documented are the `LSGT` key, the right alt
key, the right Windows key, and the left Windows key.  As we’ve seen,
Neo uses the first two options.

Say you want to use the `lv5:ralt_switch_lock` option with some layout.
This command sets up the `us` layout with this level 5 modifier key:

```
setxkbmap -option "lv5:ralt_switch_lock" us
```

So for any of the options which are documented in `man xkeyboard-config`,
use that as an argument to `-option` when using Setxkbmap.

In case these options are not enough and you want to define another key
to be the level 5 modifier, it is instructive to look at the
declarations for these options.  They seem to be in
`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level5`.  The declaration for
`lv5:ralt_switch_lock` looks like this:

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ralt_switch_lock" {
  include "level5(lock)"
  key <RALT> {
    type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift, ISO_Level5_Shift,
                        ISO_Level5_Lock, ISO_Level5_Lock, ISO_Level5_Lock, ISO_Level5_Lock ]
  };
};
```

The right side of `symbols[Group1]` declares what key or character each
level of the key should produce.  This uses all the eight possible
levels since it is supposed to *lock* the level 5 modifier when pressed
together with another level 5 shift key.  So levels 5–8 emits
`ISO_Level5_Lock` since all of these levels are accessed by holding down
the level 5 shift and some combination of the other shift keys (none to
all of them).  If you only want the shift behavior and not also the
lock-if-two-pressed behavior, you can make a simpler declaration (from
the same file):

```
// The right Alt key (while pressed) chooses the fifth shift level.
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "ralt_switch" {
  key <RALT> {
    type[Group1]="ONE_LEVEL",
    symbols[Group1] = [ ISO_Level5_Shift ]
  };
  include "level5(modifier_mapping)"
};
```

## Adding extra levels to a layout

Xkb layouts are pretty modular.  You can *include* existing layouts and
alter them.  So we can choose an existing layout with less than 5 levels
and add some levels to it.

You can make new layouts by copying the file with your layouts to
`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`, or wherever it is that your Xkb tools look
for layouts.  But this requires sudo privilege so it is not the best
solution.  Alternatively you can copy the directory structure of `xkb/`
and put your layouts in the appropriate directory under `xkb/`, namely
`symbols/`.  So say you have made a file `xkb-tree/symbols/my-layouts`.
In order to use layouts defined in this file, you can use the `-print`
option of `setxkbmap` and then pipe the output to `xkbcomp`.  This
wrapper script take the layouts as input:

```
#!/bin/sh

# `-option ""` resets all options.
setxkbmap -option "" -layout "$1" \
    -print |
    xkbcomp -I"<path-to-project>/xkb-tree" - "$DISPLAY"
```

As far as the file with the layout is concerned, let’s say that we want
to expand the “US international” layout, which uses four levels.  First
of all we set up the level 3 and level 5 shift keys in the same way that
Neo does:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "mine" {
    // US international
    include "us(intl)"
    // Set up level 3 modifiers.
    include "level3(modifier_mapping)"
    include "level3(bksl_switch)"
    include "level3(caps_switch)"
    // Set up level 5 modifiers.
    include "level5(modifier_mapping)"
    include "level5(lsgt_switch)"
    include "level5(ralt_switch)"
};
```

Now we want to add some extra characters.  Let’s just use the first four
keys of Qwerty layouts as an example.  These keys are `Q` to `R`, which
correspond to `<AD01>` to `<AD04>`.  First we need to make the keys
capable of using up to eight levels:

```
key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";
```

For the first four levels, in order to not redefine them,
we map them to `NoSymbol`.  Then we add two levels.  On level 5 we add
the arrows `←↓↑→` (†2).  On level 6 we add the direction keys.  Our
layout ends up looking like this:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "mine" {
    // US international
    include "us(intl)"
    // Set up level 3 modifiers.
    include "level3(modifier_mapping)"
    include "level3(bksl_switch)"
    include "level3(caps_switch)"
    // Set up level 5 modifiers.
    include "level5(modifier_mapping)"
    include "level5(lsgt_switch)"
    include "level5(ralt_switch)"

    // Make the following keys capable of using eight levels.
    key.type[Group1] = "EIGHT_LEVEL";

    key <AD01> { [
        NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
        leftarrow, Left
    ] };
    key <AD02> { [
        NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
        downarrow, Down
    ] };
    key <AD03> { [
        NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
        uparrow, Up
    ] };
    key <AD04> { [
        NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
        rightarrow, Right
    ] };

};
```

In order to use it we can use the wrapper script that we made:

```
./setxkbmap-wrapper "my-layouts(mine)"
```

†1: Neo is `de(neo)` in Xkb; `setxkbmap "de(neo)"`.

†2: In order to find the symbolic names that Xkb uses, search for a file
named `keysymdef.h`.  It should be under a directory named `X11/`.  You
can also use Unicode names, for example `U2192` for U+2192.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to compose this answer. I was looking for a way to use my JKLI keys as arrow keys for a while now, so this came in incredibly handy. Please enjoy these extra 50 points! (I should be able to assign the bounty tomorrow.)

Comment: Well, thanks, this is a great asnwer even if it  comes a bit late but that is exactly what I was looking for back than (but now GNOME actually does not support setting the modifier - but as long as it works using configuration files, all is well).

Comment: Your answer is straight to the point and far more clarifying than several manuals and blog posts put together. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if your level 5 key doesn't work try to configure it from the setting.  I'm putting this comment out there I couldn't reach levels 5 to 8 when i configured the level 5 key in the xkb file even though it showed it correctly on the keyboard preview (and it drove me crazy) but from the setting it just worked

Comment: After four years, I finally got to implementing this, thank you again! Now I have up to eight levels on some keys (upper and lower index on 1 and fractions).

Comment: @sup Really glad to hear that :)

Comment: My dot-emacs is now legendary. Thanks @Guildenstern and hopefully you are not dead as they say.

Comment: @JasonN Still breathing :)

Answer (score 9):

Well, after a bit of digging:

(1) Key to choose 5th level does some weird stuff (regarding some French layouts) that is not relevant to what I wanted to do. Basically it sets which key is going to act as ISO_Level5_Shift. ISO_Level5_Shift is used in some obscure layouts. This answer is based on the number of results google gives when searching for "ISO_Level5_Shift" and on [these](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-arch/2005-October/000215.html) [links](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/198759).

(2) It cannot be used to get 6 symbols out of one physical key. One way to achieve this is with the use of file .xmodmap placed in $HOME directory.

First, command

```
xmodmap -pm
```

gives what keysymbols act as various modifiers. On my system it was like follows:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x9)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c)
```

mod3 needs to set up in order to use 6 symbols with one key. This needs to be placed into .xmodmap file:

```
clear mod3
clear mod5
keycode 94 = Mode_switch
add mod3 = Mode_switch
add mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift
```

Then xmodmap -pm gave me:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x9)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Mode_switch (0x5e),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  ISO_Level3_Shift (0x6c)
```

Where keycode 94 is the key I chose to act as mod3. Keycodes of various physical keys can be found with the command line tool xev (just run it and press various keys, keycodes will show up).

Then, if I place into .xmodmap file

```
keycode 54 = 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

or run

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 54 = 1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

I get six different symbols out of one key with using altgr, shift and keycode 94 (it is a useless key next to left shift on my physical layout).

UPDATE: if you need just five symbols, it is handy to set it up like this:

```
keycode 54 = 1 2 3 3 5 6
```

It occasionaly happens to me that I get 4 instead of 3 otherwise.