# Neo/AdNW/KOY Keyboard Layout - Mod4 broken

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I wanted to test some of those new "layered" Keyboards, like Neo, AdNW or KOY. I read that when using Linux it is quite easy, compared to windows or mac, so i wanted to give it a try. I tweaked "extended input sources" and voila, all fancy layouts are there.

Problem is: If i want to use Mod4, aka Layer 4 (on german-qwertz-keys "<" and "AltGr"), this is not possible. I checked with all my three different Hardwares and got three different results:

1. IBM X220 Laptop: Both Mod4-Keys are **dead**, so i can only use Layer 1, 2, 3 and 5 (which is 2+3)
2. Lenovo T490 Laptop: Both Mod4-Keys are **inverted**, so i can use all Layers, but have to hold down Mod4 to type on Layer 1
3. Desktop PC: Both Mod4-Keys are **permanently pressed**, so i can only use Layer 4 and 6 (which is 4+2)

More Facts:

- All PCs/Laptops are using Ubuntu 20.04
- Tried with Neo2, AdNW and KOY, all get the same results (on same hardware...)
- changing keyboard in language-settings-gui or change via "setxkbmap" i get same results
- i read that CAPSLOCK should be disabled when changing layout, as CAPS aka Mod3 gets new behaviour (it is not locking...). But this has to effect on stupid Mod4

Can anyone repro this?

- Add additional Neo keyboard via "language and region" settings (i.e. German => German (Neo 2)
- Switch keyboards via SUPER+Space or language switcher in top bar
- try to type some letters and use "<" or "AltGr" as you would use shift key to "shift" to Layer 4, see keyboard layout [here](https://neo-layout.org/index_en.html)

Comment: I have got the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

## KDE Plasma desktop

To solve the issue using the KDE plasma desktop, you have to go to the advanced keyboard settings in the system settings. As you already mentioned, the first thing you need to do is to disable CapsLock, which resolves the conflict with the <kbd>Mod3</kbd> button. Then you have to open the "key to choose 5th level" submenu and select the corresponding modifier keys that you want to use as your <kbd>Mod4</kbd> (Also see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41213/what-does-key-to-choose-5th-level-in-gnome-keyboard-properties-do)). For Neo, ADNW or KOY it is the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key. If i remember correctly, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is referred to as right <kbd>Alt</kbd> in the menu). For me, this solved the problem in Ubuntu 20.04 and I can use the KOY layout without noticing any problems so far.

It is a little bit confusing that the modifier key got the number **4** while the option talks about level **5**, but it works. However, there is a small catch. If you use another layout in parallel during the learning process, enabling the <kbd>Mod4</kbd> key disables the functionality of the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key for other layouts, since it is a global setting.

After a quick search, I read that this can be solved using a bash script, but I didn't try it yet, because enabling/disabling the key in the options is quick enough for me and I only switch during my learning periods.

## GNOME

As mentioned by schwupp in the comments, the gnome settings do not provide the advanced keyboard settings menu. However, if one runs `gnome-tweaks` (you need to install it and/or `gnome-tweak-tool`), you can navigate to the "Keyboard & Mouse" submenu and hit the <kbd>Additional Layout Options</kbd> button. Another menu will pop up where you find the submenu item "key to choose 5th level". Select the "right <kbd>Alt</kbd>" and <kbd><</kbd> option. You can also set the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behaviour there.

Comment: sounds interesting, but it seems like there is no "advanced keyboard settings" menu for me? Also mentioned `gnome-keyboard-properties` form the link is not available on my 20.04 box. I can only find "input sources" via "region & language", and "keyboard shortcuts" in settings menu.

Comment: I use the plasma-desktop on my computer. I will switch to Gnome and see where I can find the corresponding menu and update my answer. But this will take some time, I am currently at work ;)

Comment: @schwupp Found it in gnome and updated my answer. Hope this helps so that you can finally start enjoying a better keyboard layout. Don't forget to install ktouch as a trainer. In case you want to use KOY, install the ktouch data files from [this GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/HJ70/koy-layout-for-ktouch).

Comment: Thank you. I tested the gnome-tweak-tool instructions on Ubuntu 20.04. This fixes the neo-layout layer 4.

Comment: My layer 4 also stopped working after some upgrades on Ubuntu 20.04 a few weeks ago. Changing _any_ settings in `gnome-tweak-tools` fixed it temporarily, but ticking the boxes „Right Alt chooses 5th level“ and „‚<Less/Greater> chooses 5th level” fixed it when restarting or locking the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your layer 4 is locked. You can try to unlock it by pressing *both Mod4* buttons together or *Shift+Mod3+Tab*. Or try to disable Num Lock on startup.

See more [here](https://github.com/neo-layout/neo-layout/blob/master/A-REFERENZ-A/neo20.txt#L60).

Comment: For me pressing both mod4 keys does nothing and `Shift+Mod3+Tab` results in a locked Layer 4 that can only be released by pressing `Shift+Mod3+Tab` again

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where Layer 4 was accessible, but behaved weirdly (moving mouse instead of printing numbers). It turns out that "Tastaturmaussteureung" was activated.

It could be deactivated with `Shift+Mod4+Numlock`, found in the same [file](https://github.com/neo-layout/neo-layout/blob/master/A-REFERENZ-A/neo20.txt#L68) as @algus

> This is relevant as my google search for this problem brought me here and these problems are extremely similar.
> I would have liked this to be a comment to the post of @algus, but I don't
> have enough reputation for comments. (Why can I do answers but not
> comments from the beginning, shouldn't it be the other way around?)

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1275449/