# Creating a custom keyboard layout with umlauts on alt + ctrl

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xfce, german

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard layout to fit my needs, based on the US layout.

#### What I want

- Alt + Ctrl + u = ü
- Alt + Ctrl + Shift + u = Ü

(same way for ö, ä, and ß)

#### Why?

1. Because getting used to the German keyboard is not how I want to waste my time
2. The hotkeys for the international one aren't convenient for me
3. Installing 3rd party software like autokey is not a good idea either: it's another daemon running somewhere instead of the kb being native (but layout editor is an ok solution)

#### System

Xubuntu (Ubuntu + Xfce) 22.04

#### What I've tried

There quite a lot of answers on this forum for this question. Many just go with the available layots.

- There's a [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show), but it doesn't answer how to bind it on alt+ctrl (or I didn't get)
- There's [KeyboardLayoutEditor](https://github.com/simos/keyboardlayouteditor), but unfortunately it requires python 2
- There's even @cuppajoeman's [keyboard layout generator](https://github.com/cuppajoeman/x11-keyboard-layout-generator), but it creates a new layout

And there are more I tried, that are either too complex, or me too stupid/lazy. If there's a good guide on what I want to actually do, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, one of the solution is using `xbindkeys`, another is registering keyboard shortcuts in your setting. https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/254442#254442

Comment: https://ictsolved.github.io/remap-key-in-linux/
.
What you want is "mapping". The link explains the basics to map keys.
.
Keyboard, language, region are set early during a fresh install. For me, a fresh install requires usually 20 minutes. 20 minutes may be considerably less time than attempting to remap a keyboard from English to German, and a fresh install ensures no bugs.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I wouldn't like to to register it as shortcuts. Regarding `xbindkeys`, as far as I understand it's also binding shortcuts, instead of editing the actual keyboard layout.

@robgrune I couldn't quite figure out how to do it with Alt+Ctrl+u. The second way described in the article is close to what I want, I already tried editing symbol files, but I didn't understand how to do it with Alt+Ctrl.

Comment: With US International, `"` + `u` gives ü, same with "Shift" gives `Ü`. AltGr+s gives ß, etc. It will be way easier to change to the US Int keyboard layout than to try writing your own layout.

Comment: You can define the 3rd level CTL+ALT and 5th level shift CLT+ALT+SHIFT key(s). And you can edit your keyboard layout and add `ü` and `Ü`. `key <AD07>  { [         u,           U,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                udiaeresis,     Udiaeresis ]    };``

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that even with regular US layout you can do

- Compose + " + u = ü
- Compose + " + U = Ü
- Compose + " + a = ä
- Compose + " + A = Ä
- Compose + " + o = ö
- Compose + " + O = Ö
- Compose + s + s = ß
- Compose + S + S = ẞ

and I guess I'm satisfied with that. To set the compose key, go to keyboard -> layout, there's a dropbox for changing the compose key

Answer (score 0):

`cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`

```
 key <AD07> { [ u, U, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
```

Set your CTL+ALT as a level5 shift and CTL+ALT+SHIFT would be a level6 shift.

Comment: Almost there. But how do I set ctrl+alt as level3 shift? I honestly have no idea what it means.

Comment: I do not know which exact keys you want to apply. Control_L, Control_R, Alt_L, Alt_Graph, ... There are so many candidates. `xev` get the code. You also may do it by `gnome-tweaks`, if you are okay with one of the combinations offered by default. `cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/de` read the file and find 3rd/5th level modifier key then you understand.

Comment: I want Alt_L + Control_L (+ Shift_L). I don't understand how to set it as level3 (and I don't honestly what "level" is here). (thanks for your help btw, I just don't understand a few remaining things)

Comment: It's simple `u` and `U` is the level 2 shift. Normally the Alt_Graph key is set to 3rd  level shift on the German keyboard layout or so. If you want a new level 3 shift, then `NoSymbol` should be `udiaeresis`. Now `xmodmap -pm` can set these nth level shifts. But I warn you, ART_L + CTRL_L  is already used for the important shortcuts.

Comment: Sorry. I genuinely don't understand. I see that German keyboard somehow mentions words level3 and level5 (cat de | grep level). I also see that "xmodmap -pm" printed some keycodes. I added what you said to my layout, but I still don't get umlautes.

Comment: You are the programmer and able to code something. https://askubuntu.com/questions/41213/what-does-key-to-choose-5th-level-in-gnome-keyboard-properties-do

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help. I still didn't get how to set those levels, and spent too much time on it either way. But it turned out that there are hotkeys out of the box, so I posted info about it in another answer

Comment: I am telling you, AltGr + u = ü for the solution, everybody else in Europe who does not use Umlauts every day. Your answer to using compose key is in this forum more than a dozen times in the past. Please search before asking.